# Issues on checkout payment page Ship To area is empty

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment

I have a magento 2.4.6 store and on the checkout/#payment page under the order summary box the Ship To: is empty, but the Shipping Method: shows: `Shipping - Shipping Method via UPS or Parcel Post`. I've seen some posts about similar situations and checked to make sure the products are not virtual and that they have weight, also I changed a value in the abstract-total.js file in the isFullMode function to return true. that did not change anything.
[image]